# Issue in JavaScript with Key Handlers

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm new to JavaScript, and made this simple code. I intended to have a red circle on a canvas that could be moved left and right with the arrow keys.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height/2;
var d = 30;
var v = 2;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
  if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
  if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, d, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  if(rightPressed) {
    x += v
  }
  if(leftPressed) {
    x -= v
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

It turned out exactly the way that I wanted, except for one thing: When the code is run, it will not respond to the left arrow being pressed until the right arrow has been pressed. I tried taking this section of the code

```
  if(rightPressed) {
    x += v
  }
  if(leftPressed) {
    x -= v
  }
```

and flipping the two "if" statements.

```
  if(leftPressed) {
    x -= v
  }
  if(rightPressed) {
    x += v
  }
```

In this situation, the inverse is true. The object will not move to the right until the left arrow key has been pressed.

I'd like both buttons to be responsive, without depending on each other. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you make a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define right and left pressed variables.  Right now your code is erroring out on the draw function when it encounters the first undefined variable.

When you handle rightPressed first and rightPressed is undefined the error is thrown and code execution stops.  That means it will never get to checking leftPressed while rightPressed is undefined.  Once you hit the right arrow, rightPressed now has a value and both checks start working.

The solution is to add the variable definition up top by the others.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height/2;
var d = 30;
var v = 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
```

Comment: IrkenInvader is correct. Here is a jsfiddle with your raw code https://jsfiddle.net/tLLsq11w/. Run it, and open up the developer tools and you will see the following errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: rightPressed is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: leftPressed is not defined

With the fix applied: https://jsfiddle.net/tLLsq11w/1/